# how to access data of an js array in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug, vis.js

I am using [twitter-js-client](https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient) and [vis timeline](http://visjs.org/docs/index.html) to develope a timeline,i can get tweets and i want to display in timeline that tweets,in index.js, i parse a json to get tweets and i pass the data which is returned by the JSON.parse() function into jade and i want to display that data on timeline by using jade.

**Here is the index.js:**

```
  router.get('/data/timeline',function(req,res) {
  twitter.getUserTimeline({screen_name:'ogedik92',count:10},error,function(data) {
    var tweets = JSON.parse(data);
    res.render('vistimeline',{Results:tweets});
  });
```

**and here is the vistimeline.jade**

```
doctype html
html
   head
      title Timeline | Basic demo

      style(type='text/css').
         body, html {
            font-family: sans-serif;
         }

      script(src='http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js')

      link(href='http://visjs.org/dist/vis.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')

   body
      #visualization

      script(type='text/javascript').
         // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
         var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
         // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
         var items = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 1, content: ''+Results[0].text ,start: '2015-04-20'},
            {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
            {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
            {id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-05-19'},
            {id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
            {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
         ]);
         // Configuration for the Timeline
         var options = {};
         // Create a Timeline
         var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the variable in client-side JS like this:

```
doctype html
html
   head
      title Timeline | Basic demo

      style(type='text/css').
         body, html {
            font-family: sans-serif;
         }

      script(src='http://visjs.org/dist/vis.js')

      link(href='http://visjs.org/dist/vis.css', rel='stylesheet', type='text/css')

   body
      #visualization

      script(type='text/javascript').
         // DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
         var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
         var Results = !{JSON.stringify(Results)};
         // Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
         var items = new vis.DataSet([
            {id: 1, content: ''+Results[0].text ,start: '2015-04-20'},
            {id: 2, content: 'item 2', start: '2013-04-14'},
            {id: 3, content: 'item 3', start: '2013-04-18'},
            {id: 4, content: 'item 4', start: '2013-04-16', end: '2013-05-19'},
            {id: 5, content: 'item 5', start: '2013-04-25'},
            {id: 6, content: 'item 6', start: '2013-04-27'}
         ]);
         // Configuration for the Timeline
         var options = {};
         // Create a Timeline
         var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```